# "Expression are not allowed at top level" in function call of a class in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

Following is my code.. I don't understand why this error shows me everytime.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class BaseLabel:UILabel
{
     func setFontAndTitle(FontName:String,FontSize:CGFloat,Title:String) {
        self.font = UIFont(name: FontName, size: FontSize)
        self.text = Title
    }

}

var lbl =  BaseLabel()
lbl.setFontAndTitle ("Areal", FontSize: 14, Title: "Check label")
```

In the last line I am getting the the error "Expression are not allowed at top level"

Comment: Pasted this into Playgrounds Beta 6 and it worked fine. Just as a side note, don't use capital letters for your argument names so that they can be distinguished easily from types.

Comment: Actually I am using the real project, and everytime it shows the same after applying small size argument

Comment: Jeff - try to use real project instead of playground. In playground i wasn't being able to even import UIKit.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban If you can't import UIKit, it means you've created a Mac OS X Playground, where UIKit isn't a valid Framework.

Comment: In Swift, top level statements work in Playgrounds (and "script" files run from the command line), but not in app class files.

Comment: @nielsbot How do we set a given swift file as a script to get round this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You trying to typing code outside of class. You need to put it in you class and enclose in function body. Please take a look at my solution:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class BaseLabel:UILabel
{
    func setFontAndTitle(FontName:String,FontSize:CGFloat,Title:String) {
        self.font = UIFont(name: FontName, size: FontSize)
        self.text = Title
    }

    func changePropertiesOfLabel(){
    var lbl =  BaseLabel()
     lbl.setFontAndTitle ("Areal", FontSize: 14, Title: "Check label")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to running it in playgrounds or a command line project,
we can also run it in the single view app!

Say our code is written in the ViewController.swift file:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class BaseLabel:UILabel {
     func setFontAndTitle(FontName:String,FontSize:CGFloat,Title:String) {
        self.font = UIFont(name: FontName, size: FontSize)
        self.text = Title
    }
}

class ViewController:UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        var lbl =  BaseLabel()
        lbl.setFontAndTitle (FontName: "Areal", FontSize: 14, Title: "Check label")
        print(lbl)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Xcode does not know when to run your `var lbl =  BaseLabel() lbl.setFontAndTitle ("Areal", FontSize: 14, Title: "Check label")`. To fix this, you must put the code somewhere where it has a certain run point (a function or playground). You could either **put it inside the viewDidLoad function in a ViewController, put it in a playground or other file that runs its code in order, or put it in a new function**

### Solution 1:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      var lbl = BaseLabel()
      lbl.setFontAndTitle(FontName: "Calibri", FontSize: 14, Title: "Check Label"
   }
}
```

### Solution 2:

Put it in a playground.

### Solution 3 (Probably the best and most efficient way):

```
func customizeLabel() {
    var lbl = BaseLabel()
    lbl.setFontAndTitle(FontName: "Calibri", FontSize: 14, Title: "Check Label"
}
```

For solution 3, run `customizeLabel()` inside a viewDidLoad or other active run point.