# Expressions are not allowed at the top level when creating a dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift

I am using Swift(Xcode 6 beta 6) and creating a dictionary like this which gives an error. I am not able to understand why it gives an error.

```
var PP = Dictionary<String, Any>()
PP["defaultServerMode"] = "Production"  // This line give error(below)
```

Error:

```
Expressions are not allowed at the top level
```

Comment: Unless you are doing this in `main.swift`, top-level code (i.e. outside a class or a function) must consist of declarations. Of course you should be able to write `var PP: Dictionary<String, Any> = ["defaultServerMode": "Production"]`

Comment: I am doing it in a plain swift file with nothing else.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Expression are not allowed at top lavel" in function call of a class in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929978/expression-are-not-allowed-at-top-lavel-in-function-call-of-a-class-in-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this, because Swift doesn't know when to execute this statement. Imagine, if you have a number of different Swift files and in each you have one expression or assignment. How would the system know which one it should execute first?
You can declare global variables, but then you must always provide an initializer (for example like dasblinkenlight's comment). Of course you can later modify the value of the variable from within any function.

Comment: So what is the best way to store values and later access them in Swift? I am a python developer so I tried to do this way. Thanks for the information.

Comment: For anything beyond 10 lines of code, use classes or structures. They can have properties, which (from a OOP viewpoint) are more appropriate to store data, because usually you don't want the entire program to be able to access your variables.